# Installing "bokeh" library upgrades Tornado to the version 5 that causes an issue with starting Python kernel in DSX Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tornado, bokeh, data-science-experience

I upgraded `bokeh` library by executing the following command:

`!pip install --user --upgrade bokeh`

Tornado version 5 dependency was installed. After upgrading the library from the DSX Notebook the kernel stops responding after restart. I see "Slow Kernel connection" dialog.
Opening another notebook for the same language displays the same error dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tornado 5.0 is incompatible with the current ipython kernel installation for DSX Notebooks. 
If you are experiencing "Slow kernel connection" issue after upgrading `Bokeh` library try the following steps:

- Switch to Python kernel with another version (e.g. if you installed Tornado 5 for "Python 2" kernel, switch kernel to "Python 3.5")
- Execute the following command in the notebook code cell: `!rm -rf ~/.local/lib/`
  This command will remove all python packages installed by user
- All Python kernels should be started normally

If Tornado 5 was installed for both Python versions (Python 2 and Python 3) you could remove user's packages by switching to `R` kernel and executing the following command:

`system('!rm -rf ~/.local/lib/')`

After that you could switch back to Python kernel.

You could upgrade `bokeh` library with the following command:

`!pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed bokeh`

In this case Tornado package will not be updated

Comment: You can probably also just downgrade Tornado by hand. It's not Bokeh that is causing an upgrade, it's `pip` that is deciding to update Tornado. Bokeh works with any Tornado version >=4.5

Comment: @bigreddot Correct, but removing it reverts to the Tornado version that is pre-installed in the environment. There's really no point in having another version installed in the user directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just suggesting another way for users who do not want to remove any other package that user may have installed in ~/.local/lib/, can simply uninstall tornado that is installed in user's python environment

For user's having issue with Python 3
Switch to R kernel and run following:-

```
system("/usr/local/src/conda3_runtime/home/envs/DSX-Python35-Spark/bin/pip uninstall -y tornado",intern=TRUE)
```

For Python 2

```
system("/usr/local/src/bluemix_jupyter_bundle.v83/notebook/bin/pip uninstall -y tornado",intern=TRUE)
```

Likely if above pip binary locations change, you can try to locate them with

```
system("which pip",intern=TRUE)
```

Thanks,
Charles.